# in laravel how to search and display student data in view by using 2 input filed "id" and and "date of join"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Present i created single input filed "id" if enter valid id it showing student ( name, email, Id). this is working Perfectly.

now i what to add one more input filed "date of join"

in this function i what to check input "id" and "date of join", is mach then show student data in view, or else it show 
("data not found") message

**MY VIEW**

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id"
            placeholder="Search users">

             <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

</form>

<div class="container">
    @if(isset($details))
        <p> The Search results for your query <b>  </b> are :</p>
    <h2>Sample User details</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>id</th>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>certificate_approval</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($details as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->student_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
       <div class="card-body">
    <img src="STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/{{ $user->student_photo }}" class="img-circle" width="90" />


                                </div>


                                    <td>{{$user->student_registration_id}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$user->student_certificate_approval}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @elseif(isset($message))
    <p>{{$message}}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

**MY ROUTE**

```
 use App\Student;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
Route::any( '/search', function(){
    $id = Input::get( 'id' );
    if($id != ""){

$user = Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' )->get();

     if (count ( $user ) > 0)
     return view( 'my-search' )->withDetails( $user )->withQuery($id);
}

     return view ( 'my-search' )->withMessage ( "No Details found!" );
} );
```

**MY MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student_lists';


    protected $fillable = ['student_name', 'student_registration_id', 'date_of_join', 'student_phone_no', 'student_photo', ];





}
```

Comment: where is you controller ? this is very bad idea using route file  for functionalities

Comment: @Hamelraj i am using only route if possible to create the controller please guide me

Comment: please check below answer , both ok if not clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "input id `and` date of joining". Both match then student details show.

```
$user = Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' )
                ->where('date_of_join', 'LIKE', '%' . $date_of_join . '%')
                ->where('approved', 'APPROVE')
                ->get();

if(!empty($user)){
     return view( 'my-search' )->withDetails( $user )->withQuery($id);
} else {
     return view ( 'my-search' )->withMessage ( "No Details found!" );
}
```

Comment: one more thing i what to check one more filed column name (approve ) value "APPROVED" if value 'APPROVED' that time only show data or else value "PENDING" , result show "No Details found!"

Comment: @user12380208 If column name `approved`. But there is not found any column in student model

Comment: @user12380208 What is column name for APPROVED?

Comment: ( column name "approved" )  and ( column value "APPROVE ", another value "PENDING" )

Comment: @user12380208 what is `date_of_join` is `null` of `blank`? or you it will not be empty .

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
  $id = Input::get( 'id' );
                               $date_of_join = Input::get('date_of_join');
                                if($id != ""){

                                    $user = Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' );
                                    if (!empty($date_of_join))
                                    {
                                        $user->where('date_of_join','=',$date_of_join);
                                    }
                                    $user = $user->get();

                                    if (count ( $user ) > 0)
                                        return view( 'my-search' )->withDetails( $user )->withQuery($id)->withDateOfJoin($date_of_join);
                                    }

                                    return view ( 'my-search' )->withMessage ( "No Details found!" );
                                } );
```

Comment: Deshmukh i got error "syntax error, unexpected '}'"

Comment: @user12380208 semi colon was missing from this line `$user->where('date_of_join','=',$date_of_join);`

Comment: @Prashanth Deshmukh thank you is working , one more thing i what to check one more filed column name (approve ) value "APPROVED"  if value 'APPROVED' that time only show data or else value "PENDING" , result show "No Details found!"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a where condition to the query to search the date

```
Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' )->get();
```

In this query you can modify it like:

```
$student = Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' );
if($dateOfJoin){
   $student->where('date_of_join', $dateOfJoin)
}
   $user = $student->get();
```

Now you can chain multiple where or any other condition to the query.

Also, you can use @forelse to show empty data like

```
@forelse ($details as $detail)
<li>{{ $detail->name }}</li>
@empty
<p>No Details</p>
@endforelse
```